# Using rich or textual to generate a grid like a chess board

Tags: python, tui, rich

I would like to know the efficient way to generate a grid (literal meaning) using `rich` or `textual`.

I have noticed the `rich.table` package so yes I can generate a grid but I didn't find a way to change the background color of a single cell. But also, I don't know how can I refer a single cell.

So maybe, it is not the good way to do it.

Which classes (from `rich` or `textual`) is more efficient for achieving a chess board like in terminal ? Should I build my own widgets ?

Comment: Take a look at the texttactoc (https://github.com/JoseAndresMedina/TextTacToe) project. That might point you in the right direction. I am trying to reverse engineer it myself at the moment.